# lightgbm how to predict_proba?

Tags: python, lightgbm

if i use lightgbm

there is two methods of using lightgbm. first method: -

```
model=lgb.LGBMClassifier()
model.fit(X,y)
model.predict_proba(values)
```

i can get predict_proba method to predict probabilities.
if i use it natively

```
import lightgbm as lgb
dset = lgb.Dataset(X, label=y)
params = {}
params['learning_rate'] = 0.003
params['boosting_type'] = 'gbdt'
params['objective'] = 'binary'
params['metric'] = 'binary_logloss'
model = lgb.train(params, dset, 100)
```

I can get predict method but predict_proba method dont exist if i use this method. anyone can advise what i did wrong?

Comment: Please create a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). That would mean 1. mentioning the version of `lightgbm` you are using 2. including the specific text of any logs or errors that have led you to conclude "predict_proba method doesn't exist" 3. modifying the provided code so anyone can run it (e.g., including code to generate `X` and `y`).

Answer (score 0):

You can only use predict_proba in [sklearn fit()](https://lightgbm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pythonapi/lightgbm.LGBMClassifier.html#lightgbm.LGBMClassifier.fit). It does not exist in lightgbm native train().

Comment: whats the workaround for using native api to predict probabilities then?

Comment: At the moment the solution is to use fit().

Comment: fit just, well.. fit the data, after that would be to predict isnt it?

Comment: When you use the sklearn fit(), you will have access to predict() and predict_proba(). But you have to prepare your datasets and parameters that are acceptable to sklearn.